# Duplicate free/busy or full calendar information between two exchange servers

Tags: exchange

We have acquired a new entity with their own AD/Exchange environment.  *Until they fully join our domain, we need to sync their exchange calendars or minimally free/busy for users.*  All users in the acquisition have a new account in our organization.

We have considered a number of options including CalDAV, but nothing seems to meet our needs.

Even a client solutions to update the NEW server with the free/busy would be workable.

Comment: What versions of exchange are at each organization?

Comment: 2007 at both locations.  They are different AD Forest as it is an acquisition.

Answer (score 0):

Would the Exchange Replication Service be suitable for you? Nice [install\config guide](http://msmvps.com/blogs/clustering/archive/2004/10/06/15140.aspx). There's [another guide](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Configuring-InterOrg-Replication-Tool.html) with screen shots if you prefer